# Get referer inside php file_get_contents

Tags: php, url

I've got some file on `www.aaa.com/file.php`

I've got another file on `www.saveme.com/file2.php`

And inside this 2nd one I call 1st one this way `file_get_contents('www.aaa.com/file.php');`

I want `www.aaa.com/file.php` to get url of site that has called it.

Is it possible?

`www.lol.com` calls `www.aaa.com/file.php`  -> it gets `www.lol.pl`

`www.another.com` calls it -> it gets `www.another.com`

Something like 'who've called me from another server and what server was it?'

Answer (score 18):

Actually, no, as it isn't as obvious as Captain Payalytic said it was, here is how to do it.

```
$referer = "http://abc.info";
$opts = array(
       'http'=>array(
           'header'=>array("Referer: $referer\r\n")
       )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($node_img, false, $context));
```

**Source:** http://thuannvn.blogspot.be/2011/12/how-to-set-referer-in-php.html

After getting a headache on the official doc, not saying a word about referers, I finally did a classic search on the web and immediately found this. Hooray!

**EDIT:** The doc says `header` should be a string though ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php ). One should check if it works with an array too.

Alternatively you should also be able to retrieve the domain's name from the IP of the request received. (Not always though)

You could also use `curl` too.

Comment: Responding to your edit: header works as both an array or a string. (I tested both ways.)

As a string you would type `'header'=>"Referer: $referer\r\n"` which is slightly shorter than your array code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the referrer as an argument to `file_get_contents`:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.aaa.com/file.php?referrer='.urlencode($referrer));
```

It is not possible for the second server to get the original referrer otherwise.

Comment: yes, since file_get_contents launch a new HTTP session, it cannot inherit the original referrer.

Comment: This code doesn't work as a general solution. (This code only works if you have control of both the source and destination URLs.) The solution provided by JeromeJ does work for all cases. I needed to determine if a site would allow you to access images there if the referer was not the same as the site's domain. JeromeJ's code enabled me to do this.

Answer (score -2):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php where you will find out about get_headers() and $http_response_header.